# How to select most recent Invoice Date by Business Account using BQL/FBQL(Acumatica)?

Tags: acumatica

This is what I've tried with the addition of so many variations using FBQL.

```
[PXDBDate]
[PXDefault(typeof(SelectFrom<ARInvoice.docDate>.
AggregateTo.Max<ARInvoice.docDate>.GroupBy<BAccount.acctCD>>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Last Invoice Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

I think the problem I'm having is how to select a date type with one value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like this?

```
    [PXDBDate]
    ////[PXDefault(typeof(SelectFrom<ARInvoice.docDate>.
    ////AggregateTo.Max<ARInvoice.docDate>.GroupBy<BAccount.acctCD>>))]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Select<ARInvoice, OrderBy<Desc<ARInvoice.docDate>>>))]

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Invoice Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

Comment: Thanks, the syntax seems right--on validation there is an error stating the ARInvoice.docDate has no implicit reference to PX.Data.IBqlWhere. I tried wrapping ARInvoice.docDate with ToString(), which didn't work. But I don't think that would fix the problem anyways. It's saying the problem is with the select.